# Trying to do a path analysis in R: lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others

Tags: r, statistics, spss

I am working with an SPSS data file. Discrete missing values are set to -999. I think this is why I am getting this error code when trying to do a path analysis in R. How can I fix this? Do I have to do something in SPSS or can I do it in R? Will scaling effect my results? My technical knowledge of statistics is rudimentary, so explain it to me like I am a 1st year psychology undergrad please.

#This is my error message:

Error in Sigma.inv * sample.cov : non-conformable arrays
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  :
lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
2: In lavaan(model, data = Conspiracies) : lavaan WARNING:
Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values.

#here is my code:

```
library(haven)
Conspiracies <- read_sav('Baseless_Beliefs.sav')
library(lavaan)

# Specify the model
model <- '
  # Exogenous variables
  Individualizing ~~ Binding
  
  # Mediators
  mean_vhnb ~ Individualizing + Binding
  mean_se ~ Individualizing + Binding
  mean_spd1 ~ Individualizing + Binding
  
  # Outcome variables
  ConsControversies ~ mean_vhnb + mean_se + mean_spd1
  Pseudoscience ~ mean_vhnb + mean_se + mean_spd1
  ClassicCoverup ~ mean_vhnb + mean_se + mean_spd1
  Magicalthinking ~ mean_vhnb + mean_se + mean_spd1
  
 #estimating the covariance of residuals for outcome
 ConsControversies ~~ Pseudoscience + ClassicCoverup + Magicalthinking
 Pseudoscience ~~ ClassicCoverup + Magicalthinking
 ClassicCoverup ~~ Magicalthinking
'

fit<-lavaan(model,data=Conspiracies)

summary(fit,fit.measures=TRUE)
summary(fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE,rsquare=TRUE)
parameterEstimates(fit)
fitMeasures(fit)
modificationIndices(fit)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not reproducible because we don’t have access to your data files. I agree the problem is most likely because of your convention that “-999 is missing”. R doesn’t know that. R uses `NA` as missing. So convert your `-999`s to `NA`s and try again. We can’t show you how to do that because you haven’t shared your data. Good luck!

Comment: Note that the read_sav function has a dedicated argument for setting SPSS iser-defined missings to NA. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Limey I checked frequencies and they didn't have missing valuese, so I set it to non. Only on item had 3 system missing values. Here is a link to my data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vPk3ZNeHV8IVCKvA23iJA3-g5qZHGgoc/view?usp=sharing